# How to access an XSD schema compiled into a BizTalk project?

Tags: xml, xsd, automated-tests, biztalk

I'm trying to add some tests to a project that ensure that our internal BizTalk schemas continue to correctly (in)validate some XML test files that don't meet our business rules.

Normally I would use the path to the XML and XSD files, however, since the XSD is part of a BizTalk project and the `BuildAction` is "BtsCompile", the file cannot be set to copy locally. I know I can use the path to the source file (this is working for me at the moment), however, this feels like a hack because the path could change for different environments, and might not even be present in some cases (ex: CI/CD).

**How can I use the schema by type (ex: `MyProject.Namespace.MySchema()`) or by XML namespace (ex: `http://myurl.com/schemas/MySchema`) to validate a sample XML file?**

If it matters, my schemas are in a BizTalk project, and my tests are in a separate Unit Test project. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 at the moment.

Comment: Are you using BizUnit? https://github.com/BizUnit/BizUnit

Comment: No, I had not heard of it before. I will definitely be checking it out though! Thanks Dijkgraaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give you a frame challenge Answer here.

> How to unit test an XSD schema...

**You don't.  Meaning, don't bother.**  You will spend more time setting up for unit tests than you would ever save catching a validate error in a unit test.

Why?  Because if the validation error causes an actual hard error, which is not always the case, you will still have a bug, you just wasted a lot of time finding it in a unit test rather than a functionality test.

Unit tests were the popular thing a couple years ago until everyone realized the ROI is usually a net negative.

Comment: Perhaps I’m not using the correct terminology - I really just would like to make sure that the schema doesn’t validate certain broken XML input files so bad data can’t creep into our system. That may not technically be a Unit Test, but I think the test still adds a valuable safety net while we are developing the schema. I will reword the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @JensEhrich You can just test it in BizTalk directly by setting "Validate document structure" to true on a test Pipeline.  That's all.  Don't waste any more time on this.